# How can 'onblur' and similar events be supported?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I want to do something like:

```
<td contenteditable=true @onblur(async (txt) => { ... })>
```

but currently it seems only `@onchange` is supported, and doesn't actually fire when `contenteditable` content is changed. I suppose the method would be to have a JS handler that calls the C# handler, but I don't know if communication can go this way. Is the best option now just to have a button that has an `onclick` handler of 'save to DB'? Or is there a better option available?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Felt the need to build a cheatsheet of available events in Blazor....Seems relevant to leave here as onblur is added.

---

### Focus events (UIFocusEventArgs)

```
onfocus        
onblur
onfocusin
onfocusout
```

### Mouse events (UIMouseEventArgs)

```
onmouseover          
onmouseout    
onmousemove   
onmousedown   
onmouseup     
onclick       
ondblclick    
oncontextmenu
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/blob/master/test/testapps/BasicTestApp/MouseEventComponent.cshtml

### Mouse wheel events (UIWheelEventArgs)

```
onwheel       
onmousewheel
```

### Drag events (UIDragEventArgs)

```
ondrag      
ondragend   
ondragenter 
ondragleave 
ondragover  
ondragstart 
ondrop
```

### Keyboard events (UIKeyboardEventArgs)

```
onkeydown    
onkeyup      
onkeypress
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/blob/master/test/testapps/BasicTestApp/KeyPressEventComponent.cshtml

### Input events (UIEventArgs)

```
oninput        
oninvalid       
onreset       
onselect        
onselectstart   
onselectionchange
onsubmit     

onchange        UIChangeEventArgs
```

### Clipboard (UIClipboardEventArgs)

```
oncopy
oncut
onpaste

onbeforecopy        UIEventArgs
onbeforecut       
onbeforepaste
```

### Touch events (UITouchEventArgs)

```
ontouchcancel
ontouchend 
ontouchmove
ontouchstart
ontouchenter
ontouchleave
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/blob/master/test/testapps/BasicTestApp/TouchEventComponent.cshtml

### Pointer events (UIPointerEventArgs)

```
gotpointercapture
lostpointercapture
pointercancel    
pointerdown    
pointerenter    
pointerleave    
pointermove      
pointerout       
pointerover     
pointerup
```

### Media events (UIEventArgs)

```
oncanplay      
oncanplaythrough
oncuechange
ondurationchange
onemptied   
onpause       
onplay     
onplaying      
onratechange 
onseeked      
onseeking      
onstalled      
onstop       
onsuspend      
ontimeupdate   
onvolumechange  
onwaiting
```

### Progress events (UIProgressEventArgs)

```
onloadstart
ontimeout
onabort
onload
onloadend
onprogress

onerror        (UIErrorEventArgs)
```

### General events (UIEventArgs)

```
onactivate      
onbeforeactivate   
onbeforedeactivate 
ondeactivate       
onended       
onfullscreenchange 
onfullscreenerror  
onloadeddata       
onloadedmetadata   
onpointerlockchange
onpointerlockerror 
onreadystatechange 
onscroll
```